# Symmetric vector least squares solution

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, symmetric-groups, least-squares, pseudoinverse

I have the similar problem as the [Symmetric linear least squares solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3344598/symmetric-linear-least-squares-solution). The least square problem of mine is that I want to find
$$ 
minimize || Ax-b ||^2,  
$$

$$
where A\in m\times n, 
$$

$$
x,b \in n\times 1
$$
However, in my problem the symmetry belongs to the vector x, i.e. x = [1 2 2 1] or x = [1 2 3 2 1]. Is there any **closed form solution** or **optimization problem** for finding a symmetric solution x ?
Any **algorithm**, **solution**, **paper** or **idea** is welcome.

(edit 1) :
I found a similar way to achieve it from the matlab implemented function and problem for designing a  [linear phase filter](https://eeweb.engineering.nyu.edu/iselesni/EL713/firls/firls.pdf)

(edit 2 ):
@user1551 You are so awesome. I have another uncorrelated question, I am fascinated with the various least square these days, I found that [gilbert strang's book](https://math.mit.edu/%7Egs/learningfromdata/) and his [corresponding opened course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-065-matrix-methods-in-data-analysis-signal) for digging out some advanced linear algebra. However, I found that your appreciated skilled can't be available from here. The question of mine is how you have this idea, i.e. symmetric constraint setting up in the vector by (I-R)x = 0. Furthermore, do you have any recommended reference or book for learning ? THX!

Answer (score 3):

Let $R$ be the reversal matrix, the anti-diagonal matrix obtained by flipping the identity matrix left-right. The constraint that $x$ is “symmetric” can be reformulated as $(I-R)x=0$. Any $x$ satisfying this constraint must be in the form of
$$
x=[I-(I-R)^+(I-R)]v=\frac{I+R}{2}v=Pv
$$
where $P=\frac{I+R}{2}$. Your constrained minimisation problem can then be reformulated to the usual unconstrained least-squares problem of minimising $\|APv-b\|^2$. Its minimisers are therefore given by $v=(AP)^+b+\big[I-(AP)^+(AP)\big]u$ or
$$
x=P(AP)^+b+P\big[I-(AP)^+(AP)\big]u,
$$
where $u$ is an arbitrary vector. In particular, $x=P(AP)^+b$ is a solution (if you take $u=0$).

Comment: Awesome closed form solution. I have further uncorrelated question as above  (edit 2), if you can offer the answer I will appreciate as the answer. Pretty thanks!

Comment: However, it also reduce the ill condition problem when deploy P matrix. Is there any penalty or constraint for confine the condition of the matrix?